# calculate start date and end date from given quarter SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get :

startdate and enddate from a given quarter from between dates

**example :**

range of dates : 2016-01-01 - 2016-12-31

1 (quarter) - will give me :

```
start date
2016-01-01
enddate
2016-03-31
```

2 (quarter) - will give me :

```
start date
2016-04-01
enddate
2016-06-30
```

and so on

Comment: "and so on" if the input dates are 2011-01-01 & 2021-12-31 (10 years) what do you expect? **ALL quarters** from the start to the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it for only Quarter name and Year, modified it as your need

```
-- You may need to extend the range of the virtual tally table.
SELECT [QuarterName] = 'Q' + DATENAME(qq,DATEADD(QQ,n,startdate)) + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(QQ,n,startdate)) AS VARCHAR(4))
FROM (SELECT startdate = '01/Jan/2016', enddate = '31/DEC/2016') d
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT TOP(1+DATEDIFF(QQ,startdate,enddate)) n 
   FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) rc(n)
) x
```

Comment: up to 1 year. but the range might be :2016-01-01-2016-09-30

Comment: @NirNiroN see it can be n number of range just change values in `SELECT startdate = '01/Jan/2016', enddate = '31/DEC/2016'`

Answer (score 0):

Check below logic to get your answer.

```
DECLARE @Year DATE = convert(varchar(20),datepart(YEAR,getdate()))+'-01'+'-01'
    DECLARE @Quarter INT = 4

    SELECT  DATEADD(QUARTER, @Quarter - 1, @Year) ,
            DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(QUARTER,  @Quarter, @Year))
```

Comment: not good for me.. i want to supply two dates: startDate and endDate. in your sample it uses GETDATE

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEADD(QUARTER, d.q, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0,GETDATE()), 0))
AS FromDate,
DATEADD(QUARTER, d.q + 1, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), -1))
AS ToDate
FROM (
        SELECT 0 UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 UNION ALL
        SELECT 3
     ) AS d(q)
```